# Qual view foi usada nesse layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

galera eu to criando um app que a pessoa faz um cadastro,e nesse cadastro tem nome,fotos e várias informações e eu queria listar essas informações e fotos dessa forma,alguém sabe oq foi utilizado ? nessa galeria vc desliza o dedo e vai carregando novas fotos [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse exemplo aí foi usado o CardView com o RecyclerView.

Existem exemplos do google pra utilizar os guidelines deles de material design e alguns tutoriais na internet.

Se você quiser um tutorial, tem esse aqui: [Getting Started With RecyclerView and CardView](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465)

Existem pessoas que vendem templates de implementações bem feitas dos guidelines do google. Um exemplo seria o MaterialX (disponível no google play).